# Database Record Has All Values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and need some help getting the results I need in a query.  My data looks like this:

```
ConsumerID  Tag
1000028041  bBROAapp
1000028041  bBROtiva
1000028041  bClsElig
1000028041  bPCAFwd
1000028041  bTOPNoRs
1000028041  bTOPNwRq
1000028041  bTOPActv
```

and I want to select a given ConsumerID only if they have all of the tag values I'm looking for.

For example, this selects all records with any of the 3 tags:

```
SELECT ConsumerID
FROM   BorrowerTags
WHERE  Tag IN('bBROAapp', 'bBROtiva');
```

Results:

```
  1000028041    bBROAapp
  1000028041    bBROtiva
```

This returns no results

```
SELECT ConsumerID
FROM   BorrowerTags
WHERE  Tag = 'bBROAapp'
AND    Tag = 'bBROtiva';
```

No Results

I only want those records where the ConsumerID has both values - not either one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to select a given ConsumerID only if they have all of the tag values

You could use:

```
SELECT ConsumerID 
FROM BorrowerTags 
WHERE Tag IN ('bBROAapp', 'bBROtiva')
GROUP BY ConsumerID 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Tag) = 2;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/MBJJV74574)**</kbd>

---

If you want entire records for consumer you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM BorrowerTags
WHERE ConsumerID IN (... above query ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`INTERSECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms188055(v=sql.110).aspx) to get your expected result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ConsumerID FROM BorrowerTags WHERE Tag = 'bBROAapp'
INTERSECT 
SELECT DISTINCT ConsumerID FROM BorrowerTags WHERE Tag = 'bBROtiva'
```

Result:

```
1000028041
```