# Find all tables containing a set of columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help with a query *that finds **all tables** containing **a set of columns*** (not one column).

I'm thinking about building a stored procedure or something that can take a comma separated list of columns and then return the table names.
Preferably it should also work with temporary tables.

I'm not asking you guys to write the SP for me, just give me a hint on what do to to find tables contain a list of columns instead of one column.

Something like

```
EXEC GetAllTablesContainingColumns 'ColA, ColB, ColC'
```

I've thought about modifying the following

```
SELECT c.SCHEMA_NAME, c.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME = @columnname
```

but don't really know how to include multiple values without ending up with

```
SELECT c.SCHEMA_NAME, c.TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME = @columnname1
      AND c.COLUMN_NAME = @columnname2
      AND c.COLUMN_NAME = @columnname3
      AND c.COLUMN_NAME = @columnname4
      ...
```

Comment: group by, having count etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Database Record Has All Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38358484/database-record-has-all-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with delimited values in a database is not recommended, to say the least. 
If you insist on using a comma delimited string as a parameter, you can probably do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetTablesWithColumns
(
    @CommaDelimitedListOfColumns varchar(8000)
)

AS

SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE ','+ @CommaDelimitedListOfColumns +',' LIKE '%,'+ COLUMN_NAME +',%'
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = LEN(@CommaDelimitedListOfColumns) - 
                  LEN(REPLACE(@CommaDelimitedListOfColumns, ',', '')) + 1

GO
```

Using `LIKE` to compare the column name against the comma delimited list,
and the combination of `LEN` and `REPLACE` to get the number of values from the comma delimited list.

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/GKRQ30459)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT c.SCHEMA_NAME, c.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.COLUMN_NAME IN (@columnname1, @columnname2, @columnname3, @columnname4)
GROUP BY c.SCHEMA_NAME, c.TABLE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4;  -- the number of columns in the list
```

If you want this to be a little more dynamic:

```
with cc as (
      select *
      from (values ((@columnname1), (@columnname2), (@columnname3), (@columnname4)) v(col)
     )
select cc.schema_name, cc.table_name
from information_schema.columns c join
     cc
     on c.column_name = cc.col
group by cc.schema_name, cc.table_name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from cc);
```